# is it possible to return more than once in javascript function

Tags: javascript

my function delete data from store but at the same time i want to save the deletion time so i tried use return twice is right like i wrote in the function or it cause any problem later ? thank for help

```
function deleteStudent( $indexedDB, student, $scope, studentId, userId) {
    return $indexedDB.openStore('student', function (store) {
        student["delete_time"] = new Date().toISOString();
        return saveItemInStore(store, student, userId);

        return store.delete(studentId);
    });
}
```

Comment: have you heard of `yield`?

Comment: A `return` statement exits the function immediately, so no subsequent `return` statement will be run.

Comment: no i did not , i'm new to java script

Comment: pointy is it posible to write in other way or i have to creat new function

Comment: Well your code has more problems than just the multiple `return` statements. You can't return *anything* from that `indexDB` callback; it's an asynchronous operation.

Comment: I guess you should have a look at [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/218196)

Answer (score 0):

The only problem this will cause is that the second return statement will never execute.

Possibly you could re-write the return statement like this...

```
return (saveItemInStore(store, student, userId) && store.delete(studentId));
```

This will return "true" if both statements succeed. Additionally "store.delete" will not execute if "saveItemInStore" fails. You'll need to determine if this is appropriate for your situation.

Comment: in both cases mine and yours the store is not excuted, maybe aboth expression are identical and the first return only excuted

Comment: What does the saveItemInStore function actually return? If the store.delete is not executing in my suggested code, then it means saveItemInStore's return value is being interpreted as false.

Comment: Both expressions aren't identical. In yours the second statement can never execute. In mine it will execute if the first returns a "truthy" value.

Comment: An explanation of a "truthy" value can be found at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy

Answer (score 0):

Objects are tailor-made to allow you to return multiple pieces of information from a function. Just create as many properties as desired on a single object and return that object. Of course, the code that calls the function needs to know that that is what is being returned and use it accordingly.

```js
var desiredInfo = myFunc();

document.write("<p>I learned both to " + desiredInfo.first + " and to " + desiredInfo.second + ".</p>");


function myFunc() {

  var objToReturn = {};

  var someAdvice = "buy low";
  objToReturn.first = someAdvice;

  var moreAdvice = "sell high";
  objToReturn.second = moreAdvice;

  return objToReturn;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/xu25hk2v/) fits your bill.

```
function mytestfunc(){
    alert("I will be called first")
    return (function(){
    alert("I will be called second");
    //saveItemInStore placeholder
    return (function(){
        alert("I will be called third")
      //store.delete placeholder
    })();
  })();
}

mytestfunc();
```

Additionally, for reference check this stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592396/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-self-executing-function-in-javascript) to know more about self executing functions.